# How to change the button type attribute in Dojo Framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dojo, dijit.form

Currently i am developing application using Dojo framework.

I want When i will click on **Install** button the attribute of that button should be change from `type = "button"` to `type = "submit"` using dojo framework.

Here is my code .

```
<button id="btn_vcenterconfiguration_Ok" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" class="submitform" type="button" value="Install"> 
<script type="dojo/method" data-dojo-event="onClick" data-dojo-args="e">
    form = getForm(this);
    doSubmit1({
        form: form,
        event: e,
        url: '{% url "vcp_home" %}',
    });

</script>
```

Also my html page showing`<span widgetId='btn_vcenterconfiguration_Ok'>` after page rendering . thats why `document.getElementById('btn_vcenterconfiguration_Ok').type = "submit"`. code is not working .

Thanx in advance :) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, according to the `dijit/form/Button` API docs, there is a `type` property you can set, for example:

```
this.set('type', 'submit'); // 'this' is your widget instance
```

However, it seems that this property is only used once, when the template is being rendered at the `buildRendering` lifecycle phase of the widget. So, updating the property is not supported out of the box, but you could implement that by yourself:

```
declare("custom.TypeButton", [Button], {
    _setTypeAttr: function(type) {
        this.type = type;
        this.valueNode.setAttribute('type', type);
    }
});
```

This will extend the `Button`, but we use a custom setter for the `type` attribute using `_setTypeAttr`.

Now, in stead of using `data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button"`, you use `data-dojo-type="custom.TypeButton"` and you modify your code to this:

```
<button id="btn_vcenterconfiguration_Ok" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" class="submitform" type="button" value="Install"> 
    <script type="dojo/method" data-dojo-event="onClick" data-dojo-args="e">
        form = getForm(this);
        doSubmit1({
            form: form,
            event: e,
            url: '{% url "vcp_home" %}',
        });
        this.set('type', 'submit'); // Change button type
    </script>
</button>
```

That should do the trick. A full example can be found on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3g46kpch/